# Fix to make transition smooth in CSS (animated search bar)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, transition

I was trying to make an animated search bar that open upon clicking on the search icon in React. I have added background colors to clearly show what is happening

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-sky-nun8c?file=/src/App.js)

The code is but lengthy but let me break it down break down quickly.

I have a flexbox nav-container. It has 2 elements - logo and search icon. Logo initially occupies all the remaining space (because of flex-grow) and search icon occupies only required amount of space.

When search icon is clicked search input expands from 0 to a fixed width and pushes the logo to left.

**Also i place the same search icon inside search input by setting the position of search-bar-mobile div to relative and search icon to absolute.**

But when search bar is closed position: absolute is immediately removed from search icon making it snap immediately to its original position. But i want to transition smoothly, can you please suggest any fix.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do two thing

First - Change the style of the following class like this

```
.search-icon-mobile-active {
  color: var(--clr-grey-5);
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Secondly place the input component after the search icon in the code

```js
<form className="search-form-mobile">
  <FaSearch
    className={`nav-icon search-icon-mobile  ${
      searchBarMobileActive ? "search-icon-mobile-active" : ""
    }`}
    onClick={() => setSearchBarMobileActive(true)}
  />

  <FaTimesCircle
    className={`search-close-button-mobile ${
      searchBarMobileActive ? "search-close-button-mobile-active" : ""
    }`}
    onClick={() => setSearchBarMobileActive(false)}
  />

  <input
    type="text"
    className={`search-input-mobile ${
      searchBarMobileActive ? "search-input-mobile-active" : ""
    }`}
    onBlur={() => setSearchBarMobileActive(false)}
  />

  <button
    type="submit"
    className="search-submit-button-mobile"
  ></button>
</form>
```

So the size of the icon will change smoothly and the width animation will depend on the input.

Comment: Thanks!! placing the input tag below does the trick.